# JavaScript to auto turn pages of a list (for digital signage)

Tags: javascript, custom-list

We're currently pulling work schedules from SQL in a Custom List and Displaying it on a TV screen for freelancers to use (Digital Signage). The tv screen can only display 30 rows so we set the list item limit to 30. Say there are 65 items (3 list pages of data), how can I input some javascript to get those list pages to automatically turn and loop every 5 seconds?

Comment: Which SharePoint version you are using?

Comment: Sorry, SharePoint 2013

Comment: You can use "no code" solution if the number of pages is relatively small and constant. Open all pages of custom list in different tabs. Install Tab Slideshow (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-slideshow/loepeenhjndiclafjgoackjblfhonogb?hl=en), it's free. Set the interval to 5 seconds and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "no code" solution if the number of pages is relatively small and constant. Open all pages of custom list in different tabs. Install Tab Slideshow (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-slideshow/loepeenhjndiclafjgoackjblfhonogb?hl=en), it's free. Set the interval to 5 seconds and that's it.

Just trying to be pragmatic here...

Answer (score 1):

Edit the list view page -> add a content editor webpart -> Edit Source and paste below code

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var totalPages = 3
    var currentPage = 1;
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(Next, 5000);
    });

    function Next(){
        if(currentPage < totalPages) {
            jQuery('a[title="Next"]').click();
            currentPage++;
            setTimeout(Next, 5000);
        }
        else
            Previous();
    }
    function Previous(){
        if(currentPage > 0) {
            jQuery('a[title="Previous"]').click();
            currentPage--;
            setTimeout(Previous, 5000);
        }
        else
            Next();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Amal. I tried this as Content editor webpart and as a jslink. Didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @BrianK can you check console for any JavaScript errors?

Comment: Amal, I am no scripting master so I apologize in advanced. I do not see any .js errors in the console. If I paste the script in and run it I get a Syntax Error. Not sure if this helps.

Comment: @BrianK can you post the error details. You can press F12 in Internet Explorer and refresh the page.

Comment: This is what I see (it's the same if I have the Content Editor on or off the page). Unless I'm not doing this right.

Comment: HTML1202: http://is running in Compatibility View because 'Display intranet sites in Compatibility View' is checked. HTML1403: Numeric character reference does not resolve to a valid character.Home.aspx, line 561 character 956.

Comment: That is not an error. Can you make sure you edited the correct page and placed the script?

Comment: I'm probably a bit out of my element here. I F12 when on the page. Go to the Script tab and refresh my page. I see 5 warnings but no errors. As for the script, right above the List I have, I added a content Editor and placed the script in the Edit Source. I get no errors on the page but nothing happens to my list.

Comment: Can you add an alert statement in `jQuery(document).ready(function(){alert('test');setTimeout(Next, 5000);});`

Comment: Added the alert and I get the Alert popup

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of how your list looks? Is the pagination buttons visible?

Comment: It doesn't seem to allow me to add pics to the comments here. My list is only showing the title. On the bottom of the list it shows me the page arrows to turn the page.

Comment: The page arrow is an `a` tag. Can you find the title of the tag using this method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589512(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: javascript: __doPostBack("ctl00$ctl40$g_09b9de0c_c413_4c59_99a8_e47fb955183b$ctl02","dvt_firstrow={22};dvt_startposition={Paged=TRUE&p_ID=__bg800053006300}")

Comment: @BrianK that is not the title, can you find `<a title=??`

Answer (score 0):

The general idea would be to use Javascript's `setInterval` method, and to change the url to add the query string which flips to the next page.

```
var page_urls = ['/page1', '/page2', ...]
var currentPage = 0

setInterval(function() {
  window.location.href = page_urls[currentPage++]
}
, 10000) // every 10 seconds
```

However I just tried changing pages in SP's list view and the query string is crazy wild.

```
#InplviewHash900ef506-8821-48db-bfda-300b2571209f=Paged%3DTRUE-p_SortBehavior%3D0-p_FileLeafRef%3DBOC%252dDashboard%252easpx-p_ID%3D361-PageFirstRow%3D31
```

Additionally, the above code wouldn't work right away because the pages array and current page variable will be wiped when you reload unless stored as session variables (or on the server or something)

Maybe someone can jump in who knows exactly the correct url to flip pages properly. However I have a secondary solution for you, if you're willing to write a little bit more code (say, using a content editor webpart + SP designer)

Get the list in JS form (however you want, REST, JSOM, CSOM/SSOM + webmethod), and use 'repeaters' to display m through n items on the page and use a setInterval to flip to n-o, o-p etc.. I'll use Angular to make things tidy.

```
<!-- include angular -->
<script src="..path to angular.js.."></script>

<!-- markup -->
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="PageController">
  <div ng-repeat="item in list | 
                  offset: currentPage * itemsPerPage |
                  limitTo: itemsPerPage">

    <!-- display whatever list data you want -->
    {{item.Title}} - {{item.Created}}
  </div>
</div>

// js
// declare angular app
angular.module('app', []);

function PageController($scope, $http, $interval) {

  $scope.itemsPerPage = 30;
  $scope.currentPage = 0;
  var totalPages;

  // get list using REST api
  $http({
    method: 'GET'   
  , url: webSiteURL // your site ie 'http://contoso.sharepoint.com'
    + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('" + yourListName + "')/items"
    + "?$select=ID,Title,Created"
  , headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
  })
  .success(function (data) {
    if (data.d.results !==  undefined) {

      // put list data in template variable
      $scope.list = data.d.results;

      // get total number of pages
      totalPages = Math.floor($scope.list.length / 30)
    }
  });

  $interval(function() {

    // if it's on the last page go back to the beginning
    $scope.currentPage = $scope.currentPage < totalPages-1
                       ? $scope.currentPage + 1
                       : 0
  }, 10000) // every 10 seconds

}

angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('PageController', PageController)

function offset {
  return function(input, start) {
    start = parseInt(start, 10);
    return input.slice(start);
  }
}

angular
  .module('app')
  .filter('offset', offset)
```